# Many to one on one table, relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have model, named Magazine. This model represents of magazines table.

```
magazines
--id
--name
```

I also have model, named Transfer. This model is represents of transfers table.
In this table I would like store information about product transfers.

```
transfers
--id
--source
--target
```

There are two important columns, source is id of magazine from I getting product, target is id of magazine where I put the product.

How should I create relationship in Eloquent model? I did something like this

```
public function source()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Magazine', 'source');
}

public function target()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Magazine', 'target');
}
```

But, doesn't work. If I call $transfer->source I only get id, which is stored in this column(integer value). But I would like get Magazine object. If I change method name from source() to magazine(), Eloquent returns Magazine object, and this is correct.

How should I create relationship if source and target indicate on the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields and methods overlap. So now you can do this:

```
$transfer->source()->getResult()->name;
```

but obviously this is not the way to handle relationships.

That said, to make it work as expected, **rename either methods or table fields**. I suggest this:

```
table transfers: id, source_id, target_id

// Transfer model
public function source()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Magazine', 'source_id');
}

public function target()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Magazine', 'target_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have only changed table fields. It's so easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `$transfer->source` you will only get the id.
You need to load your source too

```
$transfer = Transfer::with('source')->find(123);
```

and then access the name of the source

```
$nameOfSource = $transfer->source->name
```

Comment: Eager loading doesn't matter as long as `attribute` and `relationship` have the same names.